# No need to specify shape if using constant initializer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

Trying to create linear regression model with tensorflow. Now im on the step when i should create variables for weights and bias:

```
w = tf.get_variable('weights', shape = None, initializer = None)
b = tf.get_variable('bias', shape = None, initializer = None)
```

From Stanford course CS20si i read that "No need to specify shape if 
using constant initialize". But this part of code raises:

`ValueError: Shape of a new variable (weights) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.`

Does it mean that i should put shapes for these variables? I think that i loose something. Any suggestions?

Comment: @blue-phoenox its just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You should set shapes to initialize these variables. Take logistic regression as an example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,5],dtype=tf.float32,name='input')
y_=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,1],dtype=tf.float32,name='label')

w=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,1]),name='weights')
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]),name='bias')
y_pred=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,w)+b)

cross_entropy=tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1]))


train_op=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for epoch in range(1000):
        _, loss = sess.run([train_op, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: [X_train[i]], y: [y_train[i]]})
        if (epoch % 50 == 0):
            print('Epoch: {0}, total loss={1}'.format(epoch + 1, loss))
```

If you use constant to initialize like the following, you don't need to set shape.

```
a=tf.get_variable("my_variable", dtype=tf.int32,initializer=tf.constant([2, 3]))
```

Comment: So `initializer  = None` is not constant initializer and it is neccesay to put shape in tf.get_variable every time i will use tf,get_variable?